# Does the OSGi Bundle.update() method also download new dependencies

Tags: osgi, auto-update, apache-karaf

I have a similar goal as the person here: [Using OSGi to implement auto-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097169/using-osgi-to-implement-auto-update)

Essentially, I want to be able to update bundles in my applications automatically. The post above mentions that you can just call Bundle.Update(), but will that also download new dependencies if some have been added since the previous version? If so, where does it look for them?

Furthermore, what differentiates this solution with provisioning management tools, as discuses here: [What's the difference between features in Karaf and OBR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977381/whats-the-difference-between-features-in-karaf-and-obr)

That is, why would you use something like OBR vs. this Bundle.update() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `bundle.update()` only updates the individual bundle that you updated, it never does anything to any other bundles. Therefore it's certainly possible that, after the update, the bundle will no longer resolve due to missing dependencies. So this is exactly why you should use something higher-level like OBR or Karaf etc versus `bundle.update()`.